# Running two mapper on a input file and a reducer for simple hadoop mapreduce jobs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

In a simple MapReduce program, there is one input file, that after splitting each line, it will be mapped. But now I want to read each line and after split, the line, map it two times by different keys. reading one line and two maps (two times using context.write).
I read: 
[Running two mapper and two reducer for simple hadoop mapreduce jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717495/running-two-mapper-and-two-reducer-for-simple-hadoop-mapreduce-jobs)
That answered: *So just put 2 files into your input directories so that you can get 2 mappers running.* Now I should to put two same files?

Comment: I think you can write two separate mapper classes and then use `MultipleInputs` (available only with `mapred`) to pass your files to two different mappers. Haven't tried it so can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point to read line in mapper, split it and pass somewhere. Process it immediately:

```
void map(K key, Text value, Context ctx) {
    String k1 = getKey1(value);
    String k2 = getKey2(value);
    map1(k1, value);
    map2(k2, value);
}

void map1(...) { ... }
void map2(...) { ... }
```